# Importing modules into a remote PC with powershell

Tags: windows-10, powershell, remote-access, import, authorization

I can't find an answer to this issue which I can understand so forgive me if this has already been answered.

I'm trying to use self-written modules on a remote PC using Powershell.

I would like to use these modules on the remote PC without having to copy the modules to the remote PC first, as the task I want to complete will involve many remote PCs.

I've also remoted on to the remote PC in question and ran: winrm quickconfig
allowing remote management.

```
$sessionPC = new-pssession -Credential(Get-Credential) -computername WorkPC2

Invoke-Command -Session $sessionPC{
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process
    import-module "\\jumpAdmin2\c$\Users\admin\Desktop\MODULES\InstallQuietly-Application.psm1" -Force 
    import-module "\\jumpAdmin2\c$\Users\admin\Desktop\MODULES\ConsoleNotifications.psm1" -Force
}
```

I enter admin credentials after running the code but receive this notification in the host panel:

Access is denied
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Module], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
+ PSComputerName        : WorkPC2

Any way I can resolve this or understand the process better?
Thank you.

Comment: What’s the value of $env:PSModulePath

Comment: @Ramhound, I added the location of the modules into the $env:PSModulePath, but get the same result.

Comment: That wasn’t what I wanted to know. I have a reason for asking and a folloup question also.

Comment: Asked 15 hours ago and no pointers.... I see, this is a classic example of double-hop, see both answers on this related duplicate question, this is most definitely your problem: https://superuser.com/questions/1615707/using-powershell-invoke-command-to-install-applications-in-c/1615896#1615896 ..... Like I said, read over both those answers for examples and context of what's going on. The workaround in my answer does exactly what you do NOT want to do however basically.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7.4&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7.1

Comment: Thanks all, will look up these resources and post update. Much appreciated.